# Derive Distance between Points and Polygons within Radius ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity

I need to figure out the distance between points that fall within 500km of polygons. I have approximately 1000 points and 3000 polygons. For each polygon, I need the distance to all points within a 500km range.

I have tried running 'Generate Near Table' with a 500km search radius, but after letting it run for over 24 hours, there has been no progress.

I have tried running it with the points and polygons as shapefiles and as feature classes in a geodatabase.

Any other ideas or workflows that might be successful? I haven't found any other tools in ArcMap or QGIS that will do something similar to 'Generate Near Table'.

Comment: Those are tiny tables. Please [Edit] the question to provide more information on the exact formats and presence of spatial indexes. As a new user, please take the [Tour]

Comment: Check that your data is local if you are storing it in a file geodatabase. It should fly there but not on a shared drive.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually seeing the data, I'd guess that it's the complexity of your polygons that's causing the problem, or maybe geometry errors in the polygon layer. If your desired result is a distance to all points within 500km of each polygon, try splitting your polygon layer up into several smaller layers of, say, 500 polygons each and running Near Table on each smaller layer (with the full 1000-point layer) individually.